# Mongoose - condition that is valid for all elements in nested array

Tags: javascript, mongoose, filter

My documents have a nested array of objects. One field of those "item" objects is "totalPrice".

I want to be able to filter the documents in a way that it only returns docs which has an items array that completely fulfills the filter, meaning that each object in the array has a lower price than the filter.

My current query looks like this:

`MyObjModel.find({"items.totalPrice": { $lt: 100 } })`

My expectation would be that it only returns documents where each item has a price smaller than 100. However, it returns documents where only one array item fulfills the requirement, so it would return this one although the second item does not fulfill the query.

```
{
   items: [{totalPrice: 88}, {totalPrice: 120}]
}
```

How would I have to change my query object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding documents where each item has a price smaller than 100, you can find documents where no item has price bigger than or equal 100.

```
Model.find({'items.totalPrice': {$not: {$gte: 100}}})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SwcUMiaAFD4)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I chain multiple conditions together like this? E.g. if I look for documents with items between 80 and 100.

Comment: Then you can use $and combine with this answer: https://mongoplayground.net/p/DNvkt-ZPgJ9